# slick grid cell coloring

Tags: slickgrid

I need to set background color of cells in slick grid based on the data being rendered to the grid. Looking at the other posts in stack overflow, I figured out that we can use a custom formatter to do the same by returning a div. I want to accomplish this without returning another div. I did try using rowCssClass and column cssClass property but no luck. Could someone please help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grid.setCellCssStyles` as follows,

```
var row = // row Number
var rowObject = { };
rowObject[row] = { property1: "cssClass", property2: "cssClass" };
grid.setCellCssStyles(row, rowObject);
```